# file_put_contents on multiple request of XML data

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, amazon-mws

I have to make multiple (approx. 20) ListOrderItem Requests from Amazon MWS and I'm having a problem trying to figure out how to write each of those request to a single XML file.

Right now, the XML file is just being overwritten with the most recent request. When I write to csv with PHP, it just adds the newly given text to the first blank row. I was hoping xml worked the same - silly me.

This is the code I have now:

```
file_put_contents($amazonOrdersXML, ""); //clears the xml file to start

$OrderLen = count($OrderArray); //number of requests needed to make

for ($x = 0; $x < $OrderLen; $x++) {

$t = xml_attribute($OrderArray, $x);
    if (array_key_exists('AmazonOrderId', $ListOrderItemsRequest)) {
        $ListOrderItemsRequest['AmazonOrderId'] = $t;
        $try = amazonRequest($ListOrderItemsRequest, $secret);
        print_r($try);
        file_put_contents($amazonOrdersXML, $try);
  }
}
```

I think what I have to do is use curl_multi_init for the multiple requests, but if someone knows another way, I would be OH SO GRATEFUL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very dear friend helped me on this one. If you're seeing this, Wizard - xoxo.

Here's the magic:

```
for ($x = 0; $x < $OrderLen; $x++) {

$t = xml_attribute($OrderArray, $x);
    if (array_key_exists('AmazonOrderId', $ListOrderItemsRequest)) {  
        $ListOrderItemsRequest['AmazonOrderId'] = $t;
        $try = amazonRequest($ListOrderItemsRequest, $secret);
        print_r($try);
        file_put_contents($amazonOrdersXML, $try, FILE_APPEND);
        sleep(1);
}
}
```

It was a flag action ("FILE_APPEND") for file_put_contents() that did the trick. Hope this helps someone else. On to more problems.